# How to restrict user to type in kendo filter input?

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have customize filter on kendo grid but here i have small issue when i have date column in the grid i want to restrict user to type anything in filter input, Expected behavior is user should always select the date from datepicker to apply filter. How can i apply onkeydown function to the filter ?

config.js

```
getallCycles: {
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        editable: false,
        dataBound: function () {
        },
        filterable:{
          extra: false,
          operators: {
              string: {
                  startswith: 'Starts with',
                  eq: 'Is equal to',
                  contains: 'Contains'
              }
          }
      },
 columns: [
{
            field: 'assessmentDueDate',
            title: 'Cycle Assessments Due Date',
            width: '190px',
            filterable: {
              ui: function (element) {
                  'use strict';
                  element.kendoDatePicker({
                      format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                  });
                  element.onkeydown({
                    return false;
                  });
              },
              operators: {
                  string: {
                      eq: 'Is equal to'
                  }
              }
          }
          },
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add disabled attribute to the input control to disable typing

```
filterable: {
  ui: function(element) {
    element.kendoDateTimePicker(); // initialize a Kendo UI DateTimePicker
    $(element).attr("disabled","disabled");

  }
}
```

Please see the live demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@amaldevv/UNIbe)